# Setting up SSL on heroku with custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, subdomain

I am trying to set up SSL for a custom domain on heroku using the ssl-endpoint addon. My app uses Rails 3.1.0.

Suppose my custom domain is www.example.com.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420577/subdomain-for-ssl-on-heroku) and various other sources, I found that I am supposed to use secure.example.com rather than example.com as the common name when generating the certificate request.  I have a few a questions about this:

1. Do I have to forward users from example.com to secure.example.com (or do anything else with my domain registrar)?
2. Will users actually see secure.example.com rather than example.com when using ssl?
3. Will I have to change anything in my actual Rails application or config in order to get this to work?

Comment: you can use any variant of your domain name you want. but you HAVE to make sure that your secure site uses that name consistently throughout. if your cert is issued for `example.com`, then visiting `www.example.com` is going to cause name mismatch errors. and vice versa as well, cert for `www.example.com` will not properly match on `example.com.` The exception is if you get a wildcard cert ($$$) for the domain.